# Java exception explicit casting vs implicit casting

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception

Came across this piece of code: -

```
public <T> T call(final Callable<T> callable) {
    try {
         return callable.call();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
         if (exception instanceof RuntimeException) {
             throw (RuntimeException) exception; // Line 6
         } else {
             throw new RuntimeException(exception); // Line 8
         }    
    }
}
```

1. What is the need for doing a `(RuntimeException) exception` at line 6?
2. What is the difference between the exceptions being thrown at line 6 v/s line 8. Aren't they doing the same thing?

Comment: (You could better write the code as `} catch (RuntimeException exc) { throw exc; }  catch (Exception exc) { throw new RuntimeException(exc); }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code there is to transform a checked exception into a unchecked exception. In Java, checked exceptions have to be declared on a method with the `throws` keyword, while unchecked exceptions don't need to be declared on the method. `Exception` is the base class for all exceptions while `RuntimeException` (which is a subclass of `Exception`) is the base class for all unchecked exceptions.

The code on line 6 is to make the compiler happy. As `Exception` is a checked exception, by casting it to `RuntimeException` the compiler won't enforce the exception to be declared on the method with a `throws`. Line 8 wrapes the checked exception into a unchecked exception.